# Generate graphics from scheme-babel export?

Tags: org-mode, images, scheme

I'm using a nice package from a Racket user called [MetaPict](https://github.com/soegaard/metapict), however, I don't know how to export the image produced. Here's some Racket code calling MetaPict:

```
#+begin_src scheme :session mainsession :exports both
(require racket/draw metapict metapict/graph)

(set-curve-pict-size 300 300)  ; width and height of image
(ahlength  1.0)                ; size of arrow head 

(define (f x) (sin x))

(define p
  (with-window (window -12 12 -12 12)             ; xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax
    (draw (draw-arrow (curve (pt -10   0) -- (pt 10  0)))  ; x-axis
          (draw-arrow (curve (pt   0 -10) -- (pt  0 10)))  ; y-axis
          (label-rt  "x" (pt 10.2 0))                      ; label for x axis
          (label-top "y" (pt 0 10.2))                      ; label for y axis
          (color "blue" (draw (circle (pt 2 1) 3)))        ; center (2,1) radius 3
          (color "red"  (draw (graph f -10 10 #:samples 50))))))

(define (save-pict-as-svg p width height filename [exists 'replace])
  (define dc (new svg-dc%
                  [width width]
                  [height height]
                  [output filename]
                  [exists exists]))
  (send dc start-doc "An SVG Test")  ; a message
  (send dc start-page)
  (draw-pict p dc 0 0)
  (send dc end-page)
  (send dc end-doc))

(save-pict-as-svg p 300 300 "images/outtestmetapict1.svg")
#+end_src
```

No surprise, but orgmode doesn't know that the image output

```
(save-pict-as-svg p 300 300 "images/outtestmetapict1.svg")
```

should be the code block's results and then displaying it as an image. And adding `#+RESULTS:` over a hand-added `[[file:images/outtestmetapict1.svg]]` link makes it not display. I'm guessing this means orgmode does things internally with, say, gnuplot to make the generated image be the results, hence, obeying the `:exports both` . . . Any ideas how I can get this gnuplot-like behavior with Racket MetaPict? I'm guessing there is no trick, just a customization of the underlying babel code being necessary. . . .

Comment: would an `:output value file` work after changing your code to `(let ([outfile "images/outtestmetapict1.svg"]) (save...) (write outfile))` ?

Comment: Not sure. Will try.

Comment: Well, did it work?